# Как добавить атрибут микроразметки в мета-тег, генерируемый Yoast SEO?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

Yoast SEO выводит вот такой мета-тег

```
<meta name="description" content="Ремонт квартир в санкт-петербурге, ремонт квартир в спб, ремонт квартир под ключ в санкт-петербурге" />
```

Нужно добавить itemprop="description" в тег, чтобы получилось так:

```
<meta name="description" itemprop="description" content="Фото ремонта квартир в санкт-петербурге, фото ремонта спб, работы по ремонту квартир в спб" />
```

Пробовал добавить его, используя фильтр wpseo_metadesc, но он предоставляет доступ только к содержимому атрибута content, но не ко всему тегу.

Каким еще способом можно решить задачу? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде хуки для модификации этого тега не предусмотрены. Поэтому остаётся только открыть буфер до начала вывода заголовков Yoast, закрыть его после, модифицировать и вывести.

Ниже рабочий код:

```
/**
 * Start output buffer before wpseo head.
 */
function my_pre_wpseo_head() {
    ob_start();
}

add_action( 'wpseo_head', 'my_pre_wpseo_head', - PHP_INT_MAX );

/**
 * Modify and output wpseo head.
 */
function my_post_wpseo_head() {
    $head = ob_get_clean();
    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    echo str_replace( '<meta name="description" ', '<meta name="description" itemprop="description" ', $head );
}

add_action( 'wpseo_head', 'my_post_wpseo_head', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Comment: Cпасибо, решение помогло!

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.